# Many-to-Many relationship between 3 tables in Entity Framework Core 8.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, orm, many-to-many

In Entity Framework 6.0, I was able to create such relationship with a join table consist of 3 primary keys without any fluent-api configuration and just by putting some attributes on the primary keys - like this:

```
public class JoinTable 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int FirstTableId { get; set; }
    public FirstTable FirstTable { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SecondTableId { get; set; }
    public SecondTable SecondTable { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ThirdTableId { get; set; } 
    public ThirdTable ThirdTable { get; set; }
}
```

Now in Entity Framework Core 8.0, you have to configure many-to-many relationships with Fluent API (I'm a newbie to EF Core stuff) and it's done like this:

```
builder.Entity<FirstTable>()
       .HasMany(x => x.NavigationX)
       .WithMany(x => x.NavigationY)
       .UsingEntity<JoinTable>();
```

Here is what I'm going to implement:

```
public class A 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; } = [];
    public List<C> Cs { get; } = [];
    public List<JoinTable> JoinTable { get; } = [];
}

public class B 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<A> As { get; } = [];
    public List<C> Cs { get; } = [];
    public List<JoinTable> JoinTable { get; } = [];
}

public class C 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<A> As { get; } = [];
    public List<B> Bs { get; } = [];
    public List<JoinTable> JoinTable { get; } = [];
}
```

But what about a 3-table many-to-many relationship? How do you implement such a relationship?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you so kind to post an academical example of 3 tables N:M relationship?

Comment: @daniherrera - I've added 3 entities with the navigations I need.

Comment: @HoomanLimouee Are you sure you had the same classes (and especially with the same navigation properties) working in EF6? Because mapping `List<JoinTable> JoinTable` navigation properties is trivial in both frameworks, even by convention or via annotations (even though different from EF6 ones), but the other like `List<A> As` etc, (so called skip navigations in EFC) I don't think are supported in EF6.

Comment: @IvanStoev - In EF6 I don't have ```List``` navigations. From each table I just have a ```virtual ICollection<JoinTable> JoinTable {get; set;}``` navigation and I thought maybe there are some improvements in EF Core that you can have more than that. Something like what I said I'm going to implement in the question. Anyways, it seems you have to do it all by you hands. I finally found a way to create a 3-table many-to-many relationship but it wasn't from MSDN documentations. You have to create a join-table and use Fluent-API to mark their keys as a composite primary key.